# Android PDF Viewer / Reader

Tags: gratis, android, pdf, offline, pdf-viewer

I am looking for an Android PDF Viewer / Reader to replace APV PDF Viewer.

***Why?***

- It appears APV PDF Viewer may be abandoned.  It has not been updated recently, has been removed from the Google Play Store (both the free and paid versions), and the latest version is not available on F-Droid.

***Requirements***

- Must not require internet access.  If it wants internet access at all, the reason must be disclosed.
- Must be compact.  The total size when installed must be under 10MB.  (Note that Google Play Store seems to show the download file size, but no the size when actually installed.)
- Must render FAST!
- Must handle documents that contain hundreds of pages and photographs.
- Not abandoned.
- Gratis (freeware).
- No ads.

***Preferences (not required)***

- Open-source
- Ability to invert colors (white on black as well as black on white)
- Not made by Google or Adobe

Comment: Again to fill the waiting time: [PDF Stuff](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_pdf) would be the place to look. My favorite wouldn't really match your requirements: *Moon+ Reader Pro* is pretty fast and convenient – but neither open-source/freeware nor *that* compact. But it can deal with plenty other (eBook) formats as well, and has pretty good support. If that would be an option, let me know. [MuPDF](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.artifex.mupdfdemo) however might be a perfect match for you (also available on Playstore).

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy.  MuPDF is my backup choice if no one can find software to meet the above requirements.  The downside to MuPDF is the size; when installed, it is over 15MB in size.  It's surprising, given that it uses the same PDF libraries as APV (namely, the MuPDF libraries).

Comment: So should I make that an answer then? If you already tried it, you could point out the core of your experience in a comment to that (I've not used it, so I cannot contribute experiences).

Comment: @Izzy I don't think so, since MuPDF does not meet the requirements.  My experience with it was installing it, seeing how large it was once installed, and then immediately uninstalling it!  :-)

Comment: Oh... OK, I see. I was hoping you liked it somehow :) No answer then, allright.

Comment: I reckon Document Viewer from F-Droid is too slow for you.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, that meets (at least) some of your requirements: http://viewerjs.org/. Excerpt From their site:

> ViewerJS is a combination of a number of excellent open source tools that are built on HTML and JavaScript.

They offer some demos on their site. It's based on PDF.JS which is used in Mozilla and is proven to be fast.

Comment: Thanks.  That's an impressive piece of code.  Is there an Android app based on it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [PDF Viewer by Joseph Paul Cohen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=the.pdfviewer3).

It should meet, if not all, most of your listed needs:
it is the smallest PDF Viewer for Android and the less permission asking  I've ever used. It doesn't require internet access to work, in terms of size it should stay in the 10MB (thus if you decide to move it to SD size becomes a little bigger), I find it's fast, it's free and I didn't noticed ads (if they are there they are really non intrusive as I never remember seeing one).
Finally, it has night mode (color switching) and it is not made by Google or Adobe.

It is definitely worth giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend WPS Office. It isn't just a PDF viewer. As the name implies it supports Word, Excel and Power point documents as well. It is really fast in rendering and you can open multiple documents at the same time and switch between the tabs. The only requirement that is not satisfied is small size. The app is approximately 30Mbs and reaches 90 mbs after installation. But trust me, the rendering speed is SUPERB.

The only problem is you have to clean the cache manually as the app can accumulate a lot of useless data (sometimes 1Gb if you don't clean for like a month). All you've gotta do is go to your device's app manager and tap clear cache.